# monodroid library in winforms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, testing, xamarin.android

I am new to MonoDroid so maybe there is an easy answer, but so far searching hasn't turned it up...  Since deploying to the Android emulator takes _for_ever_ on my PC, I would like to put most of my logic into a separate library and test it from a separate winforms application.  Later, I can build a regular MonoAndroid application that provides the UI and just calls the library.  However, when I try to link to the MonoAndroid class library I get this message:

Warning 1   The project 'MonoAndroidClassLibrary1' cannot be referenced.  The referenced project is targeted to a different framework family (MonoAndroid)

Is there another way to achieve this objective?  Yes, I could simply create a separate standard windows library and copy/paste the code between the two, but there must be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921108%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a regular .Net 2.0/3.5/4.0/etc class library and copy (or link) your source code files into it.  Use this assembly for testing in winforms, and the Android class library copy for Android.

Of course, this will only allow you to write code that doesn't reference anything in the Mono.Android.dll assembly.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but ok thanks.  Also, it would be GREAT if there was a Linux build so I wouldn't have to boot into Windows...